# beamer doesn't show png and pdf files

Tags: beamer, graphics, pdf, png

I have included `.png` and `.pdf` files in my `beamer` presentation. When I compile the document I can't see them. The documentation I read claim that both `.png` and `.pdf` should are readable by `beamer`. How can I use the figures then?

I'm using `pdflatex` on arch-linux machine. The files are stored on a remote machine and I access them via `sshfs`.

Comment: A lot of things can go wrong, `beamer` should not be responsible for this going wrong. Try and see if the problem occurs for a normal document with the same pictures. If it does, correct your question and supply us a minimal working example.

Comment: You are right. The figure is too large. Changing the figure size fixed this.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. If you find the answer to this question you can also write-up answer and accept it. Such that it doesn't show up in the unanswered list anymore.

Comment: `beamer` itself is "just" a LaTeX class. LaTeX itself accepts PNG, JPG and PDF images if the newer compilers like `pdflatex`, `lualatex` or `xelatex` are used but not by the older `latex` (DVI mode). Always check the log file for some errors or warnings. Using `sshfs` doesn't sound great but shouldn't be an issue in general.

Comment: @percusse: In this case, zeroth has provided an answer and I have fixed the problem. Writing an answer and accepting it fills like cheating

Comment: @zeroth Can you make your comment an answer including Yotam's comment?

Comment: @percusse I would rather have this not in the bin of questions, it seams very localized and as the problem was not even in the beamer it is unlikely to ever be used again? Shouldn't we flag it instead?